# Put many arrays inside the XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm using

```
def index
  @services = Service.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @services }
  end
end
```

to render an XML with all the services.

What is the right syntax to add another array to the xml?

I mean to add for example

```
@activities = Activity.all
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
format.xml {render :xml => {:services => @services, :activities => @activities}}
```